# AUCTeX not loading its TeX-latex-mode

Tags: auctex

I have emacs 25.2.2 and installed through `M-x list-packages` AUCTeX 12.1.1.

Opening any LaTeX file gives the native latex mode, so it seems through `C-h m`:

```
LaTeX/P mode defined in ‘tex-mode.el’:  
:override advice: ‘TeX-latex-mode’
```

Based on that, and the following, I would the say the activation did not go well:

> *You can detect the successful activation of AUCTeX and preview-latex in the menus after loading a LaTeX file like 'preview/circ.tex':
>   AUCTeX then gives you a 'Command' menu, and preview-latex gives you a
>   'Preview' menu.*

What should I do?

Comment: The `override advice: ‘TeX-latex-mode’` indicates that AUCTeX is properly installed and activated and the `LaTeX/P` also indicates that you're using AUCTeX rather than the native latex-mode.

Comment: Same as said by Stefan, is also said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17778046/5986651

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to fire it up.  Do something like:

```
(require 'tex-site)
```

in yr init.el (or .emacs).

Comment: When installed via package.el, this is not needed nor useful (it even used to cause problems).

Comment: Besides comment from @Stefan, loading AUCTeX with `(require 'tex-site)` was dropped with AUCTeX version 11.81 (released 2005).

Answer (score 0):

The override advice: ‘TeX-latex-mode’ indicates that AUCTeX is properly installed and activated and the LaTeX/P also indicates that you're using AUCTeX rather than the native latex-mode

[Converting @Stefan's five-year-old comment into an answer, so it can get a vote and take this question off the 'unanswered' queue]